# Gatsby fails to parse GraphQL in template

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to generate pages using gatsby-node from Sanity headless CMS.

I have some templates that work just fine, my third template fails. It used to have the exact same structure as the other templates, I've changes the structure to use static query instead of a page like query. See the gist for all the templates.

Gatsby fails with an error stating

```
There was a problem parsing "/Users/computa/Documents/prosjekter/funka/template/web/src/templates/projectsSubPages.js"; any GraphQL
fragments or queries in this file were not processed.

This may indicate a syntax error in the code, or it may be a file type
that Gatsby does not know how to parse.

File: src/templates/projectsSubPages.js
```

My projectsSubPages.js template

```
   import React from "react";
    import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
    import Layout from "../components/layout";

    const BlockContent = require("@sanity/block-content-to-react");

    const projectsSubPages = ({ data }) => {
      const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        {
          allSanityProjects {
            edges {
              node {
                projectChildPages {
                  _rawBlockContent
                  title
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `);
      const pageData = data.allSanityProjects.edges;

      return (
        <Layout>
          {/* {pageData.map((node) => (
            <p>Hello world</p>
          ))}
          <BlockContent blocks={pageData._rawBlockContent} /> */}
          <p>Hello world!</p>
        </Layout>
      );
    };

    export default projectsSubPages;
```

My gatsby-node.js file, it's the bottom createPage that fails

```
exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const path = require(`path`);
  const { createPage } = actions;
  const projects = path.resolve("src/templates/projects.js");
  const defaultPage = path.resolve("src/templates/defaultPage.js");
  const projectsSubPages = path.resolve("src/templates/projectsSubPages.js");

  return graphql(`
    {
      allSanityDefaultPage {
        edges {
          node {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
      allSanityProjects {
        edges {
          node {
            slug
            projectChildPages {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then((result) => {
    if (result.errors) {
      reporter.panic("failed to create page ", result.errors);
    }

    result.data.allSanityDefaultPage.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.slug,
        component: defaultPage,
        context: {
          slug: node.slug,
        },
      });
    });
    result.data.allSanityProjects.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.slug,
        component: projects,
        context: {
          slug: node.slug,
        },
      });
    });
    result.data.allSanityProjects.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      if (node && node.projectChildPages && node.projectChildPages.slug) {
        createPage({
          path: node.slug + "/" + node.projectChildPages.slug,
          component: projectsSubPages,
          context: {
            slug: node.slug + "/" + node.projectChildPages.slug,
          },
        });
      }
    });
  });
};
```

See Gist for more code and graphql query return 
https://gist.github.com/AndreasJacobsen/cd3fdfd9c4ea5e9f19fe17e4c38b74d2

I can't figure out what is going wrong, but there seems to be something wrong in my GraphQL query in my template, even though I get all the data I need from that query using GraphiQL Explorer